# Template loading delay with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, delay, handlebars.js, pageload

I am working on an application that uses Ember.js and Handlebars.js. I have noticed that there can be a bit of a delay displaying templates when the page first loads. It makes sense that this happens since javascript has to create the HTML. When the page first loads it looks like a blank page has loaded, then suddenly everything appears.

Honestly, this is a problem that I can live with, but still it seems a bit awkward to me. I may just be over-analyzing things, but has anyone else noticed this and does anyone have a recommendation for how to make page loads appear more "natural"?

Comment: If your page loads a lot of things, consider showing a loading spinner  while the page loads. Take a look at this: http://bit.ly/TjeG6z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I commented above, you can show a spinner while the page is rendering, loading data etc. As an example, below is a Mixin which shows a spinner until a View has rendered:

```
App.ShowSpinnerWhileRendering = Ember.Mixin.create({
  layout: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div class="loading">{{ yield }}</div>'),

  classNameBindings: ['isLoaded'],

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.set('isLoaded', true);
    this._super();
  }
});
```

In the case where you want to wait for data to load (assuming that you use the router for showing views):

```
App.ShowSpinnerWhileRendering = Ember.Mixin.create({
  layout: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<div class="loading">{{ yield }}</div>'),

  classNameBindings: ['isLoaded'],

  isLoaded: function() {
    return this.get('isInserted') && this.get('controller.isLoaded');
  }.property('isInserted', 'controller.isLoaded'),

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.set('inserted', true);
    this._super();
  }
});
```

And mix it into your views:

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend(App.ShowSpinnerWhileRendering, {
 // ...
});
```

Then define some CSS rules to show a loading spinner (or something) on an element having a `showSpinner` class, and hiding it when it also has a `isLoaded` class:

```
.loading{
  background-image: url("spinner.png") 
  background-color: #DFDFDF
}

.is-loaded .loading {
  /* back to default styling, e.g. */
  background-image: none
  background-color: white
}
```

Comment: I can't get this working + have looked at the new docs...any ideas on what's changed?

Comment: We actually tried implementing this to no avail. We are currently looking into this: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/found-a-fun-hidden-loading-feature/1677 (thought it might help future visitors)