# Ember, show spinner after changing route

Tags: ember.js

I would like to show a spinner (loading, please wait..) when the user has to wait for data to be loaded.

Let's assume loading some data takes some considerable time (1+ seconds). Then I want to show a visual feedback that something is happening, for instance when a user navigates by pressing "next item" from

```
http://localhost:9000/#/somedata/1
```

to

```
http://localhost:9000/#/somedata/2
```

I found a few articles about this problem, however, none of them seem to work. The article here describes displaying a spinner for instance https://gist.github.com/tomdale/3981133. However, this article is outdated. I was able to get access to the isLoaded state of an array by changing {{#if isLoaded}} to {{#if content.isLoaded}}. However, content.isLoaded always is 'true' even while new data is fetched using ember-data.

Another promissing article I found was [Template loading delay with Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313305/template-loading-delay-with-ember-js). However, also here while transitioning to another url, the layout was only displayed, once the data was loaded.

I am using ember-data revision: 12 and Ember 1.0.0-RC.3.

Comment: also related is this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1830

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a solution using a combination of jQuery's [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) functions and [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/).

I run this in my App.ready function:

```
spinner: ->
opts =
  lines: 13 # // The number of lines to draw
  length: 20 # // The length of each line
  width: 10 # // The line thickness
  radius: 30 # // The radius of the inner circle
  corners: 1 # // Corner roundness (0..1)
  rotate: 0 # // The rotation offset
  direction: 1 # // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  color: '#000' # // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
  speed: 1 # // Rounds per second
  trail: 60 # // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: true # // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false # // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner' # // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9 # // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: 'auto' # // Top position relative to parent in px
  left: 'auto' #// Left position relative to parent in px

target = document.getElementById('centre')
spinner = new Spinner(opts)
$( document ).ajaxStart( =>
  spinner.spin(target)
)
$( document ).ajaxStop( =>
  spinner.stop()
)
```

centre is an empty centred div for positioning the spinner:

```
#centre{style: "position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%"}
```

The nice thing about ajaxStart is that it tracks concurrent downloads. ajaxStart fires when the first call starts and ajaxStop is only called when all ajax calls have finished. It makes for a nice spinner experience.